# jquery form validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm having a hard time with the submit handler... 
Why does the following still submit form when form fields left empty?

```
$("form").submit(function() {

$(".required").each(function() { //check each instance with class of 'required'.
if ($(this).val() == "") { //if field left blank,
return false; //halt / prevent form submission.
}
//else ..
return true; //all is ok, proceed.
});

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your `return true;` will execute for any non-empty field, thus preventing the code from checking all fields.  In addition, you are only returning out of the inner function, and not the submit handler.  You should rewrite to something like this:

```
$("form").submit(function() {

    isValid = true;

    $(".required").each(function() { //check each instance with class of 'required'.
        if ($(this).val() == "") { //if field left blank,
            isValid = false;
        }    
    });

    return isValid; //all is ok, proceed.

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:  I think it's because your `return false` is nested in an `$.each` function.